# What is the proper C++ way of mapping objects to functions?

Tags: c++

What I mean is, I'm making a program that takes parameters from the user (as many as he wishes to enter at one time) by means of the console, e.g.

```
-p /users/me/myFolder/myHtmlFile.html -d /users/me/myOtherFolder -n myHmtlFileStyles -r
```

would set the parameters `-p`, `-d` and `-n`, then run the program (cause that's what `-r` does). I've already written a function that goes through each substring surrounded by whitespace in the input string. So I suspect the n00b design pattern would be something like

```
if (this_substring == "-p")
{
    // ... run some procedure
}
else if (this_substring == "-d")
{
    // ... run some procedure
}
else if (this_substring == "-n")
{
    // ... run some procedure
}
else if (this_substring == "-r")
{
   // ... run some procedure
}
else 
{
   // ... trigger not recognized; throw an error
}
```

but I'm sure there is a more elegant and proper way to do it. For instance, is there a way of mapping `string`s to functions? Does there exist something like

```
std::map<std::string, function> triggerMap = {{"-p", function1()}, {"-d", function2()}, "-n", function3()}, {"-r", function4()}};
```

??????

Answer (score 2):

You can build an `std::unordered_map` from strings to function objects, initialize the function object with a lambda and call it based on its key:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> fns {
    {
        "-p",
        []() {
            // do stuff
        }
    },
    {
        "-d",
        []() {
            // do something else
        }
    }
};

fns[param]();
```

Comment: Any reason you chose unorderd_map over map here?

Comment: @stijn since it doesn't look like we need ordering here, the idiomatic solution for key-value lookup is a hash table which `unordered_map` is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which standard you are following. I strongly suggest to use [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (e.g. with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9 compiler, using `-std=c++11`). Then use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [anonymous lambdas closures](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html).

BTW, you could use (if on Linux) [`glibc` parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments) facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use function pointers.
But I would recommend you to just use getopt

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

In your case:

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "p:d:n:r:")) != -1)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'p':
            function(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            function(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            function(optarg);
            break;
        case 'r':
            function(optarg);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use switch and a bunch of cases. Identify the flags (-r, -n, etc), extract the character and use that as the case label. Not as elegant, perhaps, as anonymous lambda closures, but more generically C++.